# Checking for zero in Java ArrayList using contains()

Tags: java, c++, vector, arraylist, integer

I have this code snippet that is basically checking for a `0` value in a ArrayList of `long` integers.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long zero = 0;

        ArrayList<Long> alist = new ArrayList();        
        alist.add (zero);

        if (alist.contains(0))
            System.out.println ("contains zero");
        else
            System.out.println ("contains no zero");
    }
}
```

and the output I get is `contains no zero`. Rather *unnerving*! 
Is this a bug or the expected behavior?

Comment: I checked to see if C++'s `vector` (the closest equivalent to Java's `ArrayList`?) had the same behavior, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here's a sample C++ code - http://ideone.com/ID0WbK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this logical check to: `alist.contains(0L)`. This behavior is related to auto boxing/unboxing. `int` is boxed to `Integer`, and `long` is boxed to `Long`. In your list you put a long (boxed to a `Long`), then you search for an int (boxed to an `Integer`)... so you don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

peter.petrov explained what is causing the wrong output, i just wanna add that try to avoid hard code until it is necessary for you. if you code it as 
`if (alist.contains(zero))` you can get the desired result.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is an example of a "blind best practice". The name `zero` contains no extra semantic information and the local variable provides no flexibility. (i.e. it's either still a "magic number", but now you've added noise by giving it a *completely* worthless name that does nothing to address the problem; or the meaning of the number was self-evident and not "magic" to begin with.) Coding like this does absolutely nothing to improve your program; you are not avoiding hard coding.

Comment: @msrd0 i have gone through the docs here and i know how to answer and what are my privileges at the moment, anyway thank you for your advise.

Comment: @Leushenko as question states "Is this a bug or the expected behavior?" so in my opinion it is not a bug the code is doing exactly what it has to, i just added to make the answer more useful. 0 is Integer here in the code while zero is Long, Thanks to peter.petrov